# Is anything known about the entity in the Centauri system that the matrix was talking to?

Tags: neuromancer, sprawl-trilogy, mona-lisa-overdrive

At the very end of [*Neuromancer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuromancer) the matrix (the AI combination of Wintermute and Neuromancer isn't given a name) says that it's talking with another AI in "Centauri system."  The end of [*Mona Lisa Overdrive*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mona_Lisa_Overdrive) says that contact with the (non-human-derived) Centauri AI is what caused the matrix to fragment into (or create, it's not clear) the loa.

Do we know anything at all about the Centauri AI, or its communications with the matrix?  Did it attack the matrix, did it have an irreconcilable worldview? Maybe the author has made a comment about how/why he imagined this taking place, or there's something in another work?